# Can I change a page's html based on device orientation?

Tags: android, ios, css, html

I'm building a very simple page that will only ever be viewed on a phone. The purpose of the page is purely to prompt people to hold their phones in landscape mode.

What I'm hoping to be able to do is use mediaqueries or something similar to detect the device's orientation. If the user is holding their phone in portrait, I'd like them to see a message and an image asking them to hold it in landscape. Once they've rotated their phone to landscape mode a link should appear on screen for them to click. It's that simple - but unfortunately I can only find code to change a stylesheet based on device orientation, but nothing that will let me actually change the body of a page. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: If you knew you wanted to use media queries, why didn't you try looking at all of the things media queries offer?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would be better if your website works in both, portrait and landscape mode.

But as you apparently can change the stylesheet based on the device orientation, just prepare your website to make use of that: In the `body` tag create two `div`s. In one of them you put your websites content you want to display in landscape mode and in the other one you put your prompt.

Then using the media queries for orientation just use `display: none;` and `display: block;` for displaying the respective `div`s in their respective orientation.

Example for portrait mode:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    #portraitContent {
        display: block;
    }
    #landscapeContent {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

And for landscape mode, just do it the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

via Javascript you can use the global property "window.orientation"

When the user turns the phone, the event "orientationchange" is executed. For example you can handle this Event in this way:

```
    $('body').bind('orientationchange', function(e) {
    alert("Smartphone was turned");
});
```

With some lines of Javascript and CSS you can show the not-landsacape users different content:

the check_orientation function:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').bind('orientationchange', function(e) {
        check_orientation();
    });
    check_orientation();
});
```

So the function checks whether the phone is hold the "right way" or not and shows/hides the content:

```
var check_orientation = function() {
    if(typeof window.orientation == 'undefined') {
        //not a mobile
        return true;
    }
    if(Math.abs(window.orientation) == 90) {
        //portraitmode
        $('#landscape').fadeOut();
        return true;
    }
    else {
        //landscape mode
            $('#landscape').fadeIn().bind('touchstart', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        return false;
    }
};
```

tag of your content-div:

```
<div id="landscape">Bitte drehen Sie Ihr Gerät!</div>
```

and your css-entry:

```
#landscape {  
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    z-index:1999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple other ideas on how to solve this.

You can prompt the user to put the device in landscape mode by using a PopupWindow

OR you can force the device in landscape mode by putting

```
<activity....
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

in the Manifest for that activity.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS3

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Portrait styles */
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Landscape styles */
}
```